# Enlarge /home partition from /centos-root

Tags: centos7, partition

I downloaded a pre-installed version of centos 7 for VMWare from a website and it has a weird layout. Most disk space is allocated to /root but /home is running out of disk space.

Most tutorials I found online only focus on the other way around: How to move disk space from home to root, but not root to home.

I am new to Linux System, so I would really appreciate any Insight or steps I have to take to solve this issue.

Output of df -h:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# df -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    1.4G   16K  1.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    1.4G   12M  1.4G   1% /run
tmpfs                    1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root  999G  8.6G  990G   1% /
/dev/sda1                976M  247M  662M  28% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home   97M   94M  2.8M  98% /home
tmpfs                    280M   36K  280M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Output of pvs, lvs and vgs:

```
[root@centos7 ~]# pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  <999.00g    0 
[root@centos7 ~]# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
  centos   1   2   0 wz--n- <999.00g    0 
[root@centos7 ~]# lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home centos -wi-ao----  100.00m                                                    
  root centos -wi-ao---- <998.90g
```

Output of `fdisk /dev/sda2` -> p

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 1073.7 GB, 1073741824000 bytes, 2097152000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0000633d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200  2097151999  1047526400   8e  Linux LVM

Command (m for help): q 

[centos@centos7 /]$ df
Filesystem               1K-blocks    Used  Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                   1412756       0    1412756   0% /dev
tmpfs                      1429908      16    1429892   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      1429908   12132    1417776   1% /run
tmpfs                      1429908       0    1429908   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centos-root 1046909492 8966772 1037942720   1% /
/dev/sda1                   999320  252812     677696  28% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home      98980   96140       2840  98% /home
tmpfs                       285984      36     285948   1% /run/user/1000
```

I already tried to follow a tutorial that uses fdisk to create a new partition, but from what I understand I cannot do that as I do not have any unallocated space?

Comment: `How to move disk space from home to root, but not root to home.` - well ... the procedure is exactly the same. It has been asked and answered a lot of times already.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I assumed that I can only reduce a partition as long as it's unmounted and I cannot unmount root? And wouldn't it risk data loss?

Comment: Boot from a live cd image.

Comment: Or just increase the size of the disk ... or add an additional disk. It's a VM.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue :)